# Office Excel 2010 won't read in 2003

Tags: excel

I have MS Office Excel 2010 installed on my machine & with my project that generates excel files.

I specified .XLS as extension.

After the exportation, I'm having 2 difficult problems.

Problem 1. When I open these files using Excel 2010, It was asking for a question:

"The file you are trying to open,  is in a different format than specified by the file extension.."

Problem 2. When I open these files using Excel 2003, a prompt message appears:

"The file is not a recognizable format"

These files will be shared by mutiple users with different MS Office versions so I need to make my files compatible with Office Excel 2000/2003/2007/2010

Here's my current code:

```
oBook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("file1.xls", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
```

This code ignores my conditional formatting & validations:

```
oBook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("file1.xls", XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
```

I'm using late binding (CreateObject on the fly)

still haven't found the right answer

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `xlExcel9795` as the second parameter to make it work... although some feature will not be preserved since not all Excel versions you mentioned support the same Featureset as Excel 2010!

Comment: Hi, most of the users will be using format 2000/2003, I also cannot use xlExcel9795, this format will cause my validation to be ignore. validations is one of the most important part of these files

Comment: sorry - then this just won't work... for such things to work properly you need versions which support the same featureset!

Comment: This is really getting painful at a time :(

Comment: I was able to solve it using oBook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("file1.xls", XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing), I debug the program thoroughly & found out that I was just having a bad value in the part on .Interior.Color = somevalue